# SQLite on Android not removing row

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I am using SQLite in my Android app. All is great but when I add a location in my weather app and then swipe it away, it doesn't remove the location from the TABLE.

Here I get the locations, add the locations and remove it.

```
public TreeMap<String, LatLng> getSQLLocations() {
    TreeMap<String, LatLng> locations = new TreeMap<>();
    for (int i =0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) {
        mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
        String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME));
        double lat = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LAT));
        double lon = mCursor.getDouble(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LONG));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        locations.put(name, latLng);

    }
    return locations;
}

public boolean removeSQLLocation(int position) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    long id = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID));

     boolean deleted = mDb.delete(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, WeatherContract.WeatherEntry._ID + "="
            + id, null) > 0;
    return deleted;
}

public long addSQLLocation(String name, LatLng latLng) {
    double lat = latLng.latitude;
    double lon = latLng.longitude;
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION_NAME, name);
    cv.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LAT, lat);
    cv.put(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.COLUMN_LONG, lon);
    long ret = mDb.insert(WeatherContract.WeatherEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    refreshLocationNames();
    return ret;

}
```

**EDIT 1: So here's the problem. I try to remove the row but when I reload the data directly from the database, it doesn't refresh. So when I add the data to the database and try to reload, it also doesn't refresh. The problem is that it doesn't refresh on a database change but it does refresh when I restart the app.**

Here is my github database file link:

https://github.com/tsmadm/Stormy-WeatherApp/tree/SQL/app/src/main/java/com/tsm/stormy/SQL

Comment: Do you have a delete row method in your DB class?

Comment: Not sure Adam. Can you check it out for me, I'm new to SQL thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Cursors are temporary objects, and should not be kept around for a long time.

Anyway, the position in the cursor is not necessarily the same as the position in your list, especially after you have made changes, or when you're doing sorting/filtering.
Store the ID in the list, and use that to access the row later.

Comment: Thanks a lot but after some refactoring it didn't work. I added a custom object which holds the name, location and id from the SQL but when I removed it, it still doesn't work. Can you take a look at my SQL and MainActivity classes - methods "removeSQLLocation". On my github https://github.com/tsmadm/Stormy-WeatherApp/tree/SQL/app/src/main/java/com/tsm/stormy/SQL